# How to use break or continue with Laravel Eloquent Collection's each method?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5

How to use break or continue with Laravel Eloquent Collection's each method.
My code is this:

```
$objectives->each(function($objective) {
        Collection::make($objective)->each(function($action) {
            Collection::make($action)->each(function($success_indicator) {
                Collection::make($success_indicator)->each(function($success_indicator) {
                    echo 'hi';
                    continue;
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: As workaround for `break` you can use the `first` method on collection. It will stop iterating when you return the first `true` result. But it's better to show us what you are really trying to do, why you need this `break` and `continue`.

Comment: for some case we can use   `exit();`  in place of  **continue** , **return true;** **return true;** solution is given below.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To `continue`, just `return` out of the inner function. To `break`, well..

If you're using Laravel 5.1+, you can return `false` to break the loop:

```php
$objectives->each(function($objective) {
    collect($objective)->each(function($action) {
        collect($action)->each(function($success_indicator) {
            collect($success_indicator)->each(function($success_indicator) {
                if ($condition) return false;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

For older version of Laravel, use a regular `foreach` loop:

```php
$objectives->each(function($objective) {
    foreach ($objective as $action) {
        foreach ($action as $success_indicators) {
            foreach ($success_indicators as $success_indicator) {
                echo 'hi';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Documentation of e.g. 5.6 is only stating how to `break` out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-each not how to skip current item.

Comment: @Roland to skip, just `return` nothing. Will exit the current invocation of the function, and will continue to the next item in the loop.

Answer (score 99):

We can return **true/false** `true` for `continue`, `false` for `break`

**Continue:**

```
collect([1,2,3,4])->each(function ($item){
            if ($item === 2) {
                return true;
            }
            echo $item;
});
```

**Output:**
1 3 4

**Break:**

```
collect([1,2,3,4])->each(function ($item){
            if ($item === 2) {
                return false;
            }
            echo $item;
});
```

**Output:**
1

Comment: actually you can just `return;` for `continue` as in order to do `break` you need to explicit return `false`.

Comment: not working ..     return collect($models->items())->each(function ($item, $index){
            if( $item->quoteReturnDetail){  return false;  } echo "test";  });

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is working find as i want. i check all code that mentioned above. but not work. Note that my version is **Laravel -5.5**

```
 return collect($models->items())->each(function ($item, $index){
        if( !$item->quoteReturnDetail){  echo  $item ;  exit(); }   });
```